# Red Hat 5 cdrom issue

Tags: redhat, rhel5, cd-rom

In Red Hat 5 I fail to mount CDROM using: mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom  
What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We can't help you with code we cannot see.

Comment: Please attach some code or configuration or something to clarify the problem. As it is, the question is unclear and i don't see how to approach the problem to help you.

Comment: I'd start by upgrading to a version of Linux from this century. Red Hat 5 was released in 1997! (If you mean RHEL 5 then even that is still almost a decade old).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution is simple: 
you should to mount to an existing folder. 
For example: 
**mount /dev/cdrom /opt** 
This mount will work because folder /opt **already exists**.

Comment: Mounting a media device on /opt (or any other used directory) is a terrible idea.